# "Government-issued" vs. "issued by the government"

Tags: sentence-structure, exam-questions

I have a sentence improvement question :

> For a week last month, the team's 20 players were stranded because the  **government-issued passport is not up to international standards**.

I am confused between these two options:

> A) **government-issued** passports were not up to international standards.
>   B) the passports **issued by the government** were not up to international standards.

For me both sentences convey same meaning but my book says option B is better.
How is B better than A ?

Comment: To this US English speaker, A looks better than B, but both are acceptable.  Although in another way, both are pointless and redundant - aren't *all* passports issued by governments?

Comment: To add, your book most likely prefers option B because it's more proper English. Option A however is more often used in casual conversation because it's easier to say while conveying the same meaning.

Comment: Many books that purportedly teach English are not written by native speakers, or rely on rules or idioms which are outdated or limited to a particular dialect.  It sounds like your book might be one of these, since both sentences are equally acceptable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on misinformation from an "English" textbook.

Comment: @Andrew: All the more reason to correct it! It's only if the error is a simple typo or from some blatantly inaccurate source (such a as a random forum post) that we should simply dismiss misinformation as the basis for questions.

Comment: I'd be inclined to remove all mention of government.  Passports are always issued by governments (except for stateless individuals who can get passports from the United Nations in some cases, but these are exceptionally rare).  Keep the sentence as short as possible without losing clarity.  *For a week last month, the team's 20 players were stranded because their country's passports were not up to international standards.* (or *...their passports were not...*).

Comment: Example A is speaking of governments in general; example B seems to refer to a specific government.  Here in Canada, a Chilean passport would be considered to be government-issued, but if I complained about the passports issued by the government, and I haven't previously stated which government, I'm tacitly implying my own (Canadian) government.

Comment: Although these two statements have the same meaning, I prefer the second, too. But the only reason is that putting the noun first in this situation helps a person know what you are going to talk about and makes it easier to follow. However, that's a really subtle difference that has nothing to do with correct grammar. I can't figure out why this would be a test question.

Comment: Perhaps it is just that the textbook is [old](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=government-issued%2Cissued+by+the+government&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgovernment%20-%20issued%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cissued%20by%20the%20government%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgovernment%20-%20issued%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cissued%20by%20the%20government%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: To me "government-issued" sounds like a general description common to all passports, while "issued by the government" refers to specific passports. Similarly you'd say "Passports issued by the government office in X", or "Passports issued by the Obama government", etc, but regulations would require "goverment-issued ID".

Answer (score 0):

Both

> government-issued

and

> issued by the government

have the same meaning, though the first is more *efficent* in word count which is usually a preference in standard English.  Other examples of this type of phrase is

> military-issued
>   company-issued

This should not be confused with

> standard-issue

which is a generic statement of origin meaning *usual* or *customary* and never used as

> standard-issue**d**
>   The ammunition is **military-issued** and is **standard-issue** for all troops in battle.

Comment: government-issue [noun].